# Wtforms: Validation error message for SelectField

Tags: python, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a Selectfield with some options and a blank default option with a custom validator

```
class Questions(FlaskForm):
     question = SelectField('What"s up?', choices=[(None,"Please select an option"),(1,"Good"),(2,"Bad")],validators=[Required(message="Please select an option")])
     def custom_validator(self,question):
         if question == "None":
              self.question.errors += (ValidationError("Please select an option"))
```

In my routes I call :

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    #do something
else:
    #so something else
```

and my html looks like this

```
{{form.question.label}}
{{form.question.label}}
```

The custom validator seems to fire but the error message is not displayed as they normally are, e.g. when using a Required() validator on a StringField.

Am I missing something? Is there any good way of getting the tooltip error message for SelectFields?

Thanks.